# Ajax updated div with jquery event handling script is calling multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following script with `html` data in ajax response.

Here is my `ajax` response data

```
    <script>
    $(document.body).on('change','.account_name_change',,function() {
         $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'locations/get_account_location/',
               data: {'id':id,'model_name':model_name},
               success: function(data) {
                    $('.new_account_name_div').html(data);
                    common_ajax_script();
               }
         });
    });
    </script>
    <div>
         some html tags
    </div>
```

This response will be updated in some `div` in current page. In current page I have one link to get above response. See, How many times I am calling `ajax` call to get this ajax response, previous response is removed and new response automatically updated.

But script in ajax response called that much time I called ajax when I intiating

```
<script>
    $(document.body).on('change','.account_name_change',function()  this event
</script>
```

Why did I miss anything?

Comment: can you be more specific...unable to understand properly

Comment: @amit_183   I am updating web page div with ajax response. In my ajax response I have script to enable event handling page specfic. It will be come from ajax source. When I first time calling ajax , it is updating corrent div in web page and ajax response script also working fine. But I am calling second, third.. more .. That much time event is called for script in ajax response

Comment: What is in `common_ajax_script()`?

Comment: @manassorn it is nothing but updating some label content..

Comment: Can you make it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?